# Python Selenium get element doesn't locate the element

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following element.
I tried css / xpath / class to locate the element but it failed.
I think the reason of the failure is because another img at the bottom of the pic shares the same class and attribute name.
I used find_elements as well but it could not detect the element either.

I even used absolute path but this could not get_attribute('src')
`'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/button/picture/img'`

For reference, the full xpath for the second img:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/button/picture/img
```

[image]

I'm trying to save a product img from the following product page.
https://www.sephora.com/product/squalane-vitamin-c-rose-oil-P416563?icid2=skugrid:p416563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate this element according to it's `src` attribute as following:

```
//img[contains(@src,'sku/s2382166-main-zoom')]
```

i.e.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'sku/s2382166-main-zoom')]")
```

**UPD**
This should work for all the similar pages on that web site

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-comp='Carousel ']//img[contains(@src,'-main-zoom')]")
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem because I'm going to do this job for other web pages that have the same class and attribute values but different src.

Comment: So how do you want to do that? You do not share a link to the web page, do not tell us the logic of your searches. The only information you provided is a picture of this particular element.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the link. 
https://www.sephora.com/product/squalane-vitamin-c-rose-oil-P416563?icid2=skugrid:p416563

Comment: And what is the logic of your flow?

Comment: I figured out the reason why the element cannot be found. It gets activated when the element is visible on the screen. So now my question is do I have to scroll it down until it finds the element and get the element or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do xpath indexing for `same tag` and `same attributes`  :-

```
//img[contains(@class, 'css')]
```

let's say above xpath represent more than one web element in DOM.

You can locate the first element like this :

```
(//img[contains(@class, 'css')])[1]
```

second webelement like this :

```
(//img[contains(@class, 'css')])[2]
```

and so on..

or you can use `find_elements` as well :

```
all_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@class, 'css')]")
all_names[0].click() #to click on first element

all_names[1].click() #to click on seconf element
```

Comment: I tried this one and It cannot detect an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below XPath based on the index for the multiple tag with same name and attribute, Just change the index of it [1][2]

```
((.//button[@class='css-1flj7f7']//img)[1])
```